# hi my command is not run in python out command but it is work well in python shell why ? I am learning python

Tags: python

[image: pic1]

[[image: pic2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bE7H
please help me my code is running in python shell but in command out put is not running

Comment: Try running the file in cmd. By climbing your directory `cd path_to_file`. Then: `python3 file_name.py`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck